# handleChange is undefined in react js

Tags: reactjs

Im getting an error saying handleChange is undefined whenever im using an arrow function and not binding the method to "this" inside the class constructor. I was watching a tutorial where the instructor said the we can define our own method using arrow function to overcome the problem of binding the method to "this".
Here is my Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import CardList from "./cardlist_component";
import SearchBox from "./search-box";
class  App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
      this.state = {
        monsters: [],
        searchField: ""
      }

      //  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(user => this.setState({monsters:user}));
    }

     handleChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({searchField:e.target.value});
    };
    


  render(){
    const { monsters,searchField } = this.state;
    const filteredMonsters = monsters.filter(whatever => 
      whatever.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
      )
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBox handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        <CardList monsters={filteredMonsters}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

 
export default App;
```

I had to downgrade my React and create-react-script a little bit for syncing my code with the tutorial. Here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "monsters-rolodex",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my searchbox code :

```
import React from 'react';
import "./search-box-styles.css";

const SearchBox = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="search">
            <input type="search" 
            placeholder="search monsters" 
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            />
        </div>

    );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

And the screenshots:
[image: vscode]

[image: powershell]

[image: browser]

[image: console]

My index code :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Please take a look at my index.js and my package.json file

Comment: Your instructor wasn't lying. Can you post the full error message?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code. Can you include the error message and stacktrace in your question?

Comment: In your "SearchBox" component, check whether you have declared a handleChange property.

Comment: Lemme post the screenshot.

Comment: i declared the handleChange props in SearchBox sir. @rdr20

Comment: Can you attach the SearchBox code? Perhaps you are not declaring correctly handleChange within SearchBox

Comment: added everything, please take a look. @NicoleDouglas

Comment: is search-box.js in the same directory as App.js?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem guys!!!!!

I upgraded the react and react-dom to 16.13.1 and react-scripts to 3.4.3.
Then changed my index.js. New index.js code :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
// import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

// ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

I think it has something to do to with the new

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
```

code, which was not there earlier because I downgraded my react-scripts.
**Thanx for the replies though :)**

Answer (score -1):

Your fat arrow function has not been assigned to a const, Anyway
Change your fat arrow function to a normal function because "this" keyword cannot be used to access the properties of a fat arrow function"

```
function handleChange (e) => {
      this.setState({searchField:e.target.value});
    };
```

Comment: You really should make an effort to try out what you post in your answers.

Comment: please take a look at my index.js and my package.json file

Comment: Thnx Everyone :)